# Node js NPM cheerio turning " into &quot

Tags: html, json, node.js, quotes, cheerio

My application is requesting a server and getting back html.

When the html comes back i am running it through cheerio and modifying the domain names found in the html.

when stringified Json is being returned cheerio is replacing the " with &quot which is causing it to not be able to be parsed by javascript.

the "s in the HTML are not changed to &quot by cheerio. Can anyone please tell me why it is changing for the stringified Json and not the HTML and also tell me how to stop it changing to &quot

Cheerios output of my HTML

```
<div id="et-info">
    <span id="et-info-phone">+44 0000 000000</span>
     <a href="mailto:hello@newdomain.com"><span id="et-info-email">hello@newdomain.com</span></a>
</div>
```

Cheerios output of un-parsed Json string

```
{&quotresult&quot:&quotsuccess&quot,&quotredirect&quot:&quothttp:\/\/www.domain.com\/checkout\/order-pay\/3798?key=wc_order_55d7344aa233b&quot}
```

I have already tried adding

decodeEntities: true

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html[key], { decodeEntities: true });
```

Comment: Why are you parsing JSON with cheerio?

Comment: Im not im just passing the stringified Json into cheerio. If the content type is returned text/html the string is passed into cheerio so urls can be modified.  the content type is returned text/html for both HTML strings and stringified json strings. Seen as i cannot tell if the string is stringified JSON or HTML both type os string have to be passed in. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting decodeEntities to false will fix what is happening.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html[key], { decodeEntities: false});
```